# grep regular expressions + capture rpm's version

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression, rpm

we want to check if following rpm's version are installed , so we did as:

```
rpm -qa | egrep -c 'python-argcomplete-0.3.7-1|postgresql-libs-9.2.13-1.el7_1.x86_64'
```

since higher version of `postgresql-libs` can also installed as - `postgresql-libs-9.2.19-1.el7_1.x86_64`

then we try to capture both versions as following but without success

```
 rpm -qa | egrep -c 'python-argcomplete-0.3.7-1|postgresql-libs-9.2.[^0-9]-1.el7_1.x86_64'
```

expected results should be 2 but we get 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[^0-9]` matches any character *outside* 0-9, so your regex won’t match any package version you’re likely to encounter. If you want to match 13 or later, you’d need `(1[3-9]|[2-9][0-9])` (assuming the last component of the version won’t reach 100).

You could ask `rpm` directly:

```
rpm -q python-argcomplete-0.3.7 'postgresql-libs-9.2.*'
```

This will match any 9.2 version of `postgresql-libs`, which might not be exactly what you’re after, but in many cases it should be good enough.